# FFMpeg open a DVD VOB chain?

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd, vob

I'm new to FFMpeg so this may be a dumb question, but I don't see the answer in the documentation.

I want to decode frames from a DVD vob files. Opening the first VOB in the group works fine, but how do I tell ffmpeg to continue on to the next VOB and read all the VOBs on a DVD?

I have the VOB files in a folder on a hard disk.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

VOB format is a subset of [mpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOB), so you should be able to combine the VOBs you want to read in just as you would mpeg data: by concatenating them together.

```
cat first.VOB second.VOB third.VOB | ffmpeg -i - outfile.mp4
```

Hoisting [Matt Gallagher's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241630/ffmpeg-open-a-dvd-vob-chain/8349419#comment17256301_8349419) to increase longevity/visibility:

> Newer versions of ffmpeg support concatenation as an operator on the input file. So you could use... `ffmpeg -i concat:VTS_01_0.VOB\|VTS_01_1.VOB\|VTS_01_2.VOB outfile.mp4`

Comment: Doesn't that copy the vobs to a new combined file first? (which would take several minutes for a DVD)

Comment: No.  The concatenated output from `cat` is piped directly to `ffmpeg` reading from stdin.  That's what the `-i -` indicates.  There should be no difference in speed.

Comment: Newer versions of ffmpeg support concatenation as an operator on the input file. So you could use...  ffmpeg -i concat:VTS_01_0.VOB\|VTS_01_1.VOB\|VTS_01_2.VOB outfile.mp4

Comment: In Windows command prompt, you can also use double quotes to make the pipe character explicit. Otherwise, you'll get a VLC error.

Answer (score 17):

You can actually use ffmpegs builtin concatenation functionality, which is what I think you're looking for:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:$(echo *.VOB|tr \  \|)" -f mpeg -c copy -sn -y combined.mpg
```

See: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

Comment: you should remove `-sn` since that just strips subtitles which you probably don't want . You should also be able to remove `-f mpeg`

Comment: The 'mpeg' format is simply not in the ffmpeg cli documentation

Answer (score 6):

The built-in concatenate functionality seems to be *NIX based and didn't work on Windows for me. On Windows [VobMerge](http://www.evilmaster.net/?page=tools) seemed to work to join the relevant VOB files (which for the main film on a DVD seemed to be the set starting at 1GB in size).

***Addenda***

You can also join VOB files in Windows [directly from the command line](http://www.videoredo.net/msgBoard/showthread.php?5732-What-is-the-best-way-to-join-multiple-DVD-VOB-files):

```
copy /b "vob1.vob" + "vob2.vob" + "vob3.vob" "voboutput.vob"
```

You can omit the quotes if there are no spaces in the filenames, but be sure to remember the `/b` and all the `+` signs.

Answer (score 0):

in windows I preferred to "refactor" concatenation, and also not to rely on predefined filenames:

```
copy /b  e:\VIDEO_TS\vts*.vob  temp.vob
ffmpeg -i temp.vob .... newfile.ogg
```

/b means: binary copy; otherwise newlines and such are treated differently.

Caveats:

- there are sometimes VOB files that aren't part of the movie, and I couldn't find out an automated way to detect which is which
- on slow I/O systems this adds a huge time hog: it takes time to write and read the temp file.